# How to write the caption of a english table in Persian when using xepersian package?

Tags: tables, xetex, captions, xepersian

I am writing a report using the `documentclass{report}` and `xepersian` package. 
I have some tables in english but I want the caption to be in persian. Since I use the `xepersian` package, I have to put the table in a `latin` environment and I think because of that I cannot write the caption in persian.

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}‎
‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
‎\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{B Nazanin}‎
\begin{document}
‎\begin{latin}‎
‎\begin{table}[h!]‎‎
\large
‎\centering‎
‎\begin{tabular}{|l|}‎ 
 ‎\hline‎ 
 ‎\textbf{Proximal Forward-Backward Splitting}\\ [0.5ex]‎ 
 ‎\hline‎
 ‎set $x_0 = A^Tb$‎ , ‎n=0 \\‎ 
 ‎choose the number of iteration‎, ‎$N_{it}$‎, ‎and the step-size‎, ‎$\gamma_{n}$\\‎
 ‎\textbf{for} $n=1$ to $N_{it}$ \textbf{do} \\‎
‎\qquad $ x_{n+\frac{1}{2}} = x_n‎ + ‎\gamma_n A^T(b-Ax_n)$\\‎
‎\qquad$x_{n+1} = prox_{\tau \varphi \gamma_n}(x_{n+\frac{1}{2}})$\\‎
 ‎\textbf{end}\\‎
 ‎\hline‎
‎\end{tabular}‎
‎\caption{الگوریتم شماره دو}‎
‎\label{table:2}‎
‎\end{table}‎
‎\end{latin}‎ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: i dont have xepersian on my system, so I cant try but i would imagine that it would suffice to simply interchange the ordering. Just encapsulate the tabular environment by latin (so that end{latin} is BEFORE the caption)

Answer (score 6):

You have two options.

1. You want your caption label in LTR (english).

   In this case simply use

   ```
   \caption{\rl{الگوریتم شماره دو}}
   ```

   MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
   \usepackage{xepersian}
   \settextfont[Scale=1.3]{B Nazanin}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{latin}
   \begin{table}[h!]
   \large
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Proximal Forward-Backward Splitting}\\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    set $x_0 = A^Tb$ , n=0 \\
    choose the number of iteration, $N_{it}$, and the step-size, $\gamma_{n}$\\
    \textbf{for} $n=1$ to $N_{it}$ \textbf{do} \\
   \qquad $ x_{n+\frac{1}{2}} = x_n + \gamma_n A^T(b-Ax_n)$\\
   \qquad$x_{n+1} = prox_{\tau \varphi \gamma_n}(x_{n+\frac{1}{2}})$\\
    \textbf{end}\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{\rl{الگوریتم شماره دو}}
   \label{table:2}
   \end{table}
   \end{latin}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Output:

   [image]
2. You want your caption label in RTL (persian).

   In this case, encase only the `tabular` environment in a `latin` environment, instead of the whole `table`.

   MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
   \usepackage{xepersian}
   \settextfont[Scale=1.3]{B Nazanin}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h!]
   \large
   \centering
   \begin{latin}
   \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Proximal Forward-Backward Splitting}\\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    set $x_0 = A^Tb$ , n=0 \\
    choose the number of iteration, $N_{it}$, and the step-size, $\gamma_{n}$\\
    \textbf{for} $n=1$ to $N_{it}$ \textbf{do} \\
   \qquad $ x_{n+\frac{1}{2}} = x_n + \gamma_n A^T(b-Ax_n)$\\
   \qquad$x_{n+1} = prox_{\tau \varphi \gamma_n}(x_{n+\frac{1}{2}})$\\
    \textbf{end}\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{latin}
   \caption{الگوریتم شماره دو}
   \label{table:2}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Output:

   [image]